# How can I add a condition to my Firebase query in Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a locationbased App as part of an university project where the user should be able to "drop certain messages in hin surrounding for the other users to see. I'm using Ionic v4 and Firebase as my Database. Unfortunatly I'm pretty new to Ionic and Firebase, so I don't really know what to do if I don't find the answer to my problem on here, so I figured I might as well just ask.

A little more background to this: I got the said *drops* the user can write, now I want the other users to be able to upvote and downvote these *drops*. The *drops* are visible in an openstreetmap with [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). I got everything to work as intended so far but now I want to get the top 20% of all *drops* based on there score and change the icon shown on my map. I thought I can achieve this buy adding another database query to my original one, which just gets every *drop* from my database. I'm pulling the database entries with an `ionic service`.

This is my orginal query to get every entry:

```js
private dropsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Drop>;
private drops: Observable<Drop[]>;

this.dropsCollection = db.collection('drops', ref =>
    ref.where('createdAt', '>=', validMinTime)
);
```

And here is the query to get the *kingDrops*:

```js
private kingdropsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Drop>;
private kingDrops: Observable<Drop[]>;

// 2 should be replaced dynamicly with the total amount of drops*0.2
const topDrops = 2; 

this.kingdropsCollection = db.collection('drops', ref =>
    ref.orderBy('score', 'desc').limit(topDrops)
);
```

As far as I know the syntax should be alright, but how can I implement this query as a "condition" in my Frontend? I need to be able to dynamicly determine which one of my *drops* is a *kingDrop* and change the icon accordingly. Here is the Code of my **home.page.ts**

```js
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as Geolib from 'geolib';

import leaflet from 'leaflet';
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
import {Drop, DropService} from '../../services/drop.service';
import {AppComponent} from '../../app.component';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss']
})
export class HomePage {

    myDrops: Drop[];

    @ViewChild('map') mapContainer: ElementRef;

    map: any;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public dropService: DropService,
        public appComponent: AppComponent,
        public userService: UserService
    ) {}
    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.loadmap();
    }
    loadmap() {
        const positionIcon = leaflet.icon({
            iconUrl: '../../../assets/icon/position.png',
            shadowUrl: '../../../assets/icon/position-shadow.svg',

            iconSize: [30, 30], // size of the icon
            shadowSize: [30, 30], // size of the shadow
            iconAnchor: [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            shadowAnchor: [2, -2], // the same for the shadow
            popupAnchor: [0, 0] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });
        this.map = leaflet.map('map').fitWorld();
        leaflet.tileLayer(
            'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/positron/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=JrASdfPCkNw3CYBKAD6E',
            {
            attributions:
            'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 15
            }
        )
        .addTo(this.map);
        this.map.locate({
            setView: true,
            maxZoom: 10,
            minZoom: 15
        })
        .on('locationfound', e => {
            const markerGroup = leaflet.featureGroup();
            const marker: any = leaflet
            .marker([e.latitude, e.longitude], {
                icon: positionIcon,
                zIndexOffset: -1000 // put the markers on top of the location marker
            })
            .on('click', () => {
                console.log('Position marker clicked');
            });
            markerGroup.addLayer(marker);
            this.map.addLayer(markerGroup);
        })
        .on('locationerror', err => {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
        this.loadMarkers();
    }
    loadMarkers() {
        const greyDropIcon = leaflet.icon({
            iconUrl: '../../../assets/icon/grey-drop.png',
            shadowUrl: '../../../assets/icon/drop-shadow.svg',

            iconSize: [25, 30], // size of the icon
            shadowSize: [25, 30], // size of the shadow
            iconAnchor: [0, 0], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
            shadowAnchor: [2, -2], // the same for the shadow
            popupAnchor: [-3, -5] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
        });

        this.dropService.getDrops().subscribe((drops: any) => {
            drops.forEach(singledrop => {
                if (this.dropService.isDropVisible(singledrop)) {
                    const dropGroup = leaflet.featureGroup();
                    // check visibleDrops array of user for drops and add them
                    const dist = this.checkDropDistance(singledrop);
                    if (dist < 1500 && singledrop.score > -10) {
                        this.setDropVisible(singledrop);
                    } else if (singledrop.score > -10) {
                        const drop: any = leaflet.marker([singledrop.latitude, singledrop.longitude], {
                            icon: greyDropIcon
                        })
                        .on('click', () => {
                            console.log('Marker clicked, but out of range');
                        });
                        dropGroup.addLayer(drop);
                        this.map.addLayer(dropGroup);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    // ... 
}
```

I've tried to implement the *kingDrops* just like the *drops* above like this:

```js
this.dropService.getKingDrops().subscribe((drops: any) => {
    //..
});
```

But it didn't work out and it would be duplicated since the original drops are already on my map.. I need some sort of condition to determine if a *drop* is a *kingDrop* or not and implement the icon accordingly but I don't know the syntax to write such a condition..

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I propose that you add an optional boolean parameter in your 'Drop' model to indicate a kingdrop.
Since your king drops are few, you should then loop through each item and search your original array to find matches using the method [indexof](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)
You should then change the optional parameter of the drop at that array index to true, then use this variable to load your icons
Example: